# Review audit flaw for updated answer!

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, disputed-review-audits

This is the message you got when SE says that you fail the audit

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass.

I have carefully looked the answer and I found that:

- The answer used to be a low-quality answer and got downvoted
- The user, who gave the answer, had updated the answer to a proper answer after that.
- SE has nothing to do with the downvoted answer and ...
- SE continues using the updated answer to give audit reviewers. And I think it is a flaw that causes a fail negative.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you link the review you failed?

Comment: How can I check my review history? thx

Comment: If you go to the queue you failed, you can press history to view the reviews you did